# Get JSON objects from a JSON object

Tags: java, android, json

This is the data for different tabs so, I have retrieved the data for each lecture, which can be random.
How do I get the value of key day? And also these 1, 2, 4, 6 objects can be random so how to get the length of each one of these objects?

```
{
 "tab1":
    {"lecture1":
        {"day":"1"},
     "lecture2":
        {"day":"1"},
     "lecture4":
        {"day":"1"},
     "lecture6":
        {"day":"1"},
     "lecture8":        
        {"day":"1"}
    },
 "tab2":
    {"lecture3":
        {"day":"1"},
     "lecture2":
        {"day":"1"},
     "lecture5":
        {"day":"1"},
     "lecture8":
        {"day":"1"},
     "lecture2":        
        {"day":"1"}
    },
}
```

Please help me the figure out the number/count of objects in each JSON object.
It does have array in it so, I can not use them.

Comment: Is the json format is fixed?.. Can you change the json object if required?

Comment: Yes this json format is fixed.I can't change this reply.

Comment: ok. May I know the reason why this format is fixed?.. Is there any specific reason why this format is used?

Comment: the api is developed by our university's it branch which is in different city . its gonna take 1 month to change the format .

Comment: some how, i m trying this method lets hope if this work.         jObject = new JSONObject(contents.trim());
        Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

        while( keys.hasNext() ){
            String key = (String)keys.next();
            if( jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ){

            }
        }

Comment: Sorry. I can't help you in that case. Hope you get solution from others soon. Good luck. :)

Comment: @Hemant that is invalid JSON.

Comment: @Hermant which parts of this are fixed? do the tabN names always consist of tab1, tab2, tab3 for instance? can you post a valid json example of the data you actually get and highlight which parts are dynamic and and which parts are fixed?

Comment: @hector its done man!! check the 5th comment and 
no offence . its Hemant .

Comment: Sorry about getting your name wrong, my eyesight could be better, glad you solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some how, i did it. Check This method.

```
jObject = new JSONObject(contents.trim());
Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();
while( keys.hasNext() ){
String key = (String)keys.next();
if( jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ){
//get the values
}
}
```

Comment: dont  u think of commenting anything rude .